# DM-script for Gatan STEM dector control

Tags: hardware-interface, dm-script

Does anyone know the commands for Gatan STEM detector control? Specifically, I am looking for the command to change "Gain (%)", for Gatan BF/DF STEM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported/documented script interface for the detectors.

However, there are two commands `STEMSetDarkOffset()` and `STEMSetPMTVoltage()` which might be what you need, but use/test them cautiously and at own risk. I have not used them myself so far.